# Bash script manual execute run normally but not with crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Hello i have a script like this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash


ARSIP=/apps/bea/scripts/arsip
CURDIR=/apps/bea/scripts
OUTDIR=/apps/bea/scripts/out
DIRLOG=/apps/bea/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/log
LISTFILE=$CURDIR/tmp/file.$$
DATE=`perl -e 'use POSIX; print strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime time-86400;'`

JAVACMD=/apps/bea/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/sparcv9/java

HR=00

for (( c=0; c<24; c++ ))
do
    echo $DATE $HR
    $JAVACMD -jar LatencyCounter.jar LatencyCounter.xml $DATE $HR
    sleep 1
    cd $OUTDIR
        mv btw_120-180.txt btw_120-180-$DATE-$HR.txt
        mv btw_180-360.txt btw_180-360-$DATE-$HR.txt
        mv btw_60-120.txt btw_60-120-$DATE-$HR.txt
        mv failed_to_deliver.txt failed_to_deliver-$DATE-$HR.txt
        mv gt_360.txt gt_360-$DATE-$HR.txt
        mv out.log out-$DATE-$HR.log
    cd -
    let HR=10#$HR+1
        HR=$(printf %02d $HR);
done

cd $OUTDIR

tar -cf latency-$DATE.tar btw*-$DATE-*.txt gt*$DATE*.txt out-$DATE-*.log
sleep 300
gzip latency-$DATE.tar
sleep 300
/apps/bea/scripts/summaryLatency.sh
sleep 300
rm -f btw* failed* gt* out*

#mv latency-$DATE.tar.gz ../$ARSIP
cd -
```

It basically execute jar files in same directory as this script and then tar the result, gzip it and execute another bash file then delete all of the previous collected files. The problem is i need this script to run daily and i use crontab to do that. It still return empty tar file but if i execute it manually it works well..I also have other 4 scripts running in crontab and they work good..i still can't figure out what is the main reason of this phenomena

thank you

Comment: Redirect the cron stderr output to a log file and see what it contains. Maybe perl is not in the path. Do you get any output?

Comment: Another 4 scripts also has a line with that perl stuff and it works..Well about the output, normally it should generate 2 files (a gzip file usually 6 until 12 MB and a 1 KB file) but with crontab it gives me a 52 KB gzip file and an empty file..

Comment: "My script works from the command line but not from cron" is a FAQ almost as old as Unix itself. Did you try Google?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. It turned out a environment issue.
Maybe you can use env command to find what's miss in cron.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536683/why-my-svn-backup-shell-script-works-fine-in-terminal-but-fails-in-crontab

Comment: Yes i've tried it, google's result basically are absolute path and environtment issue, i also include export classpath but it still the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you execute `$JAVACMD -jar LatencyCounter.jar LatencyCounter.xml $DATE $HR`, you're not in the directory containing LatencyCounter.jar. You might want to `cd $CURDIR` before you enter the `for` loop.

Comment: I revised the script with wrote it again from zero and it looks like this was the issue, though i was late closing this question but i thank you for your suggestions :D

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a stab: your script is run by /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash.

Try explicitly running it with bash at the cron entry, like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /your/script
```

Comment: I revised the script with wrote it again from zero and it looks like the issue is like @glenn said, though i was late closing this question but i thank you for your suggestions :D

Comment: Not sure why this helped me though. I had `#!/bin/bash` anyway.

Comment: I had the exact same issue the `#! /bin/bash` did not help either